# Netty User Events

Tags: netty

For processing any user generated events in Netty(4.0.34) we use `fireUserEventTriggered(event)` on `ChannelHandlerContext`.

On calling `fireUserEventTriggered` method `userEventTriggered(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object evt)` of the handler next in pipeline is called where the generated event can be subsequently handled.

However in the `userEventTriggered` method of the next handler I am unable to access the `AttributeMap` which is stored in pervious handler. Does netty creates a new context for user events?

Comment: Can you show your code that accesses the attribute map?

Comment: Answered your question based on the information you provided. I can improve the answer with code examples if you provide some examples of what you're exactly trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AttributeMap is defined on a per-handler basis. It is a way to store state for a given handler-pipeline combination and, since a handler can be added to more than one pipeline, a given handler instance can even have several ChannelHandleContexts associated to it (as specified in the [JavaDoc](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandlerContext.html))

When you access the `ChannelHandlerContext` instance of a given handler, you're accessing the state of *that* handler in this given pipeline.

To transfer data between handlers one way is to model your user event so that it stores the data you want to transfer, then you can retrieve it later in a subsequent handler.